# PHP Ajax no muestra resultado (CERRADO)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

necesito ayuda con mi codigo php no se si lo estoy haciendo bien pero.. tengo este script:

```
$('#procesaPedido').on('click', function() {
        var storage = {};
        for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
            var key = localStorage.key(i);
            storage[localStorage.key( i )] = localStorage[key];
        }       
        var carritojs=JSON.stringify(storage);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:{"carrito":carritojs},
            success:function(data){
                console.log("enviado");
            }
        });
    });
```

y se envia a la misma pagina que es php donde tengo:

```
<?php
          if(isset($_POST['carrito'])) 
          {
            echo $_POST['carrito'];
            exit;
          }
        ?>
```

esto no me muestra el echo, no se si no llego el item a php o si no lo puedo mostrar de esta forma ayudaa

Comment: creo que no haz entendido como se usa Ajax, 
ajax envía una petición a una pagina y obtiene un result. esto no quiere decir que puedas ejecutar php otra vez en tu misma pagina. una vez que el lado del servidor termina su operación no puedes interactuar directamente con. En tu result "data" seguramente esta todo el html de la pagina (incluyendo el resultado de echo $_post['carrito']), te recomendaria que dentro del success pusieras console.log(data)

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora entendi PHP y Ajax, lo resolvi enviando la consulta con un form y convirtiendo el archivo php a html, y enviando la consulta a otro archivo php

Comment: Correcto, lo mejor es hacer una nueva pagina de PHP y cambiar los headers a html (o json text para poderlos leerlo)

Comment: soy nuevo en el foro como te doy puntos y cierro la pregunta?

Comment: publica tu comentario como respuesta (no se puede considerar mi comentario una respuesta) pero le puedes dar votos si quieres. 

creo que después de 48 horas puedes seleccionar tu propia respuesta como respuesta correcta.